# sliding fragment android

Tags: android

С помощью [этой](https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr) библиотеки можно сделать слайдинг активностей, как в телеграме. Есть ли такая библиотека, только для фрагментов? У этой такой возможности нет.

Comment: А [стандартный класс `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/screen-slide.html) что , не подходит?

Comment: Не, как использовать ViewPager, что бы добиться такого эффекта.